# Use Fullcalendar in two aspx pages

Tags: asp.net, fullcalendar

I Want to use Fullcalendars in my two different ASPX pages one is to ADDEvents and another is to ViewEvents with same JS and CSS How can i do this??

-Sindhu.A

Answer (score 1):

1. You can save your js and css in javascript file and css file and reference them from your aspx pages.
2. You can create your own usercontrol that will wrap FullCalendar control and use your usercontrol.